# Delete [EXTRACT] written when copying two lines Imacros

Tags: google-chrome, extract, imacros

```
adress1
adress2
```

When copying and pasting two lines of text as above.

```
adress1[EXTRACT]adress2
```

But I would like to paste this as below. Please teach me.

```
adress1
adress2
```

I am using:
Chrome 70.0.3538.102
Win10_x64
imacros10.0.5forCR (free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, when doing several Extracts, iMacros will separate them using this '[EXTRACT]' Separator, that when saving the Content to a '.CSV' using the 'SAVEAS' Command, will be converted to the '.CSV' Separator, usually a Comma.

Using 'EVAL()' + 'replace()' *usually*, you can replace it with whatever you want...
Instead of 'replace()', I prefer to use 'split()' like I had already mentioned in your previous Qt to achieve the Equivalent to a Global 'replace()' (that would require REGEX) and that will keep working even if you have more than 2 Addresses...:

```
SET !EXTRACT adress1[EXTRACT]adress2
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z=s.split('[EXTRACT]').join('<BR>'); z;")
PROMPT EXTRACT:<BR>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR><BR>Addresses:<BR>_{{!VAR1}}_
```

(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, Pale Moon v26.3.3 (=FF47), Win10_x64.)

**EDIT:**
And to include the Case of '#EANF#' (xN) and in any Position => See Content of '!VAR2' in the 'PROMPT':

```
'SET !EXTRACT adress1[EXTRACT]adress2
'SET !EXTRACT #EANF#[EXTRACT]adress2
'SET !EXTRACT adress1[EXTRACT]#EANF#
'>
'SET !EXTRACT address1[EXTRACT]address2[EXTRACT]address3
'SET !EXTRACT #EANF#[EXTRACT]address2[EXTRACT]address3
'SET !EXTRACT address1[EXTRACT]#EANF#[EXTRACT]address3
SET !EXTRACT address1[EXTRACT]address2[EXTRACT]#EANF#

SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z=s.split('[EXTRACT]').join('<BR>'); z;")
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.split('#EANF#[EXTRACT]').join(''); y=x.replace('[EXTRACT]#EANF#',''); z=y.split('[EXTRACT]').join('<BR>'); z;")
PROMPT EXTRACT:<BR>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR><BR>Addresses_VAR1:<BR>_{{!VAR1}}_<BR><BR>Addresses_VAR2:<BR>_{{!VAR2}}_
```

(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, Pale Moon v26.3.3 (=FF47), Win10_x64.)

Notice the use of 'replace()' for 'y', I could have used 'split().join()' again also but all but an eventual final '#EANF#' should have already been "handled" by the 'x' part, then a simple 'replace()' is "good enough" to handle that last '#EANF#'.

See and reactivate all 'SET !EXTRACT' Lines to test different Cases and different possible Positions for '#EANF#'.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering. Thanks to your answer, I solved it. I really appreciate you.
For example, if 'address 2' is an empty value and # EANF # 'is copied to' VAR 1 ', how do I make it blank?

Comment: Yeah, well, not sure what "I solved it." means..., you don't need to ask Qt's if you can answer/solve them by yourself I would think... (=> How do you solve it...?)  + For your '#EANF#' Case, produce an Example with such Content....

Comment: "do" = "did" ("Comments can only be edited for 5 min", => a bit stupid..., if the 'Edit' Button remains active...!)

Comment: OK, I've edited my Sol to include the Case of '#EANF#' (xN) and in any Position(s), see '!VAR2' in the 'PROMPT'... and all Cases in 'SET !EXTRACT' that I tested...

Comment: "I solved it." means ..., does the mean that it contains the nuance of self-solving? Thank you for your advice. I thought "Thanks to" mean "thanks for your help". I need to study English ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply again :D